# Choosing where to echo statement

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I was rewriting my old ugly code into something more practical as I will be adding allot of features that will interlink, so a clean code is a must now.

I was doing everything in functions so I had 18 little forms in a page and 18 little functions echoing in that same page for example.

```
echo getstatement($username);
echo $getname($username);
echo $getemail($username);
echo $gethistory($user);
```

These are all forms not something you see when you open the page, so I would do

```
if (isset($_POST['username']) { $username = $_POST['username']; }
```

Anyways I changed the code to print out where I want it like before by using simply one variable called message that I assign when each form is submited.

so now it's

echo $message;

Great, all of them were fine except the ones that were based of while loops.
I check history using a while loop and then echo the mysql rows using $row['column']; , alright now it echos at the top of the page in the corner.

Can I simply save the while loop as a variable and then echo the whole loop when it's done?

EG code:

```
while ($row = $query-> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                        echo "<tr><td>";
                        echo $row['name'];
                        echo "</td><td>";
                        echo $row['invoiceid'];
                        echo "</td><td>";
                        echo $row['description'];
                        echo "</td><td>";
                        echo $row['time'];
                        echo "</td></tr>";

                    }
```

This used to work well when it was a function but now it's not as good. So how am I supposed to save this in a variable that I can echo where I want.

Comment: `$_post` is a superglobal with MUST be in uppercase. change it to `$_POST` --- `$_POST['username'];`

Comment: @Fred-ii- my bad was writing it manually forgot to put it in caps

Comment: Ah ok. Just checking ;-) answered a question yesterday to that same affect, where it was in lowercase. Turned out to be the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can put the loop in a function, then call the function wherever you want it to appear in your html  - 
(remember to put all the necessary blocks in the function though)

```
   function whileLoop(){
   while ($row = $query-> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                    echo "<tr><td>";
                    echo $row['name'];
                    echo "</td><td>";
                    echo $row['invoiceid'];
                    echo "</td><td>";
                    echo $row['description'];
                    echo "</td><td>";
                    echo $row['time'];
                    echo "</td></tr>";

                }
   }
```

and then in the html

```
 <?php whileLoop() ?>
```

Comment: How reliable is this? I have around 7-10 of these I feel like it'll jumble up

Comment: if you want them all in one place, just combine them in one function and choose where you want to call it.

Comment: I don't really get your question, its going to work no matter how many times you use it, the question is is that going to solve your issue.